# Bell peppers changing too quick

Tags: bell-peppers

I have 4 bell pepper plants. Same type of soil,  planters, spot and sun. 2 of them don't start to turn color until they are larger which is normal. The other 2 change to red while they are still tiny and fall off. Their size is no larger than a thumb. Any suggestions?